# How to use JAX-WS in Jboss using Maven

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2, jboss7.x

I have been trying to find tutorials on how to start creating web services and clients in Jboss in conjunction with Maven. My team and I decided to go with the command line when learning Java EE for class. We have a project basically done, but are now at the point in the class where we need to create web services. The tutorials on using our current setup are non existent so its hard to get the overall picture when most [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html) use an IDE that does most of the work. I was able to deploy the following and get XML back, but can't get a client running to parse the info somehow:

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;

@WebService
public class Hello {

    private String message = new String("Hello, ");

    public void Hello() {}

    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return message + name + ".";
    }


}//end of class
```

I am hoping to get some help on either great tutorials on my current issue to get a better idea or actual quick explanations to help me understand it all.

Answer (score 0):

There is very good material for Java EE on the [JDF](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/) site. There are also several [quick starts](https://github.com/jboss-jdf/jboss-as-quickstart) that were developed for Java EE 6.

You might be particularly interested in the [jax-rs-client](https://github.com/jboss-jdf/jboss-as-quickstart/tree/master/jax-rs-client) quick start.

Comment: I appreciate the links. Unfortunately we aren't using JSFs or restful services, but rather soap. Either way this will be helpful outside of class.